# MAUI ListView cannot bind ItemsSource to ObservableCollection<Type>, raises "Value does not fall within the expected range"

Tags: xaml, maui

My ViewModel (I use CommunityToolkit.MVVM):

```cs
public partial class ViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<string> _items = new ObservableCollection<string>()
    {
        "abc", "def", "ghi"
    };

    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<Type> _types = new ObservableCollection<Type>()
    {
        typeof(int), typeof(string), typeof(double)
    };
}
```

My View:

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="1*,1*">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Types}" Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Binding *Items* will work, binding to *Types* will raise "Value does not fall within the expected range" error on Windows machine, but the code works fine in an Android Emulator.

Comment: What do expect from using an `ObservableCollection<Type>` and binding to it from a `ListView`?

Comment: I use ObservableCollection so that when the collection changes, the listview will update too. Actually I tested List<Type>, it didn't work too. So I guess the problem is with the System.Type, not the ObservableCollection.

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be `System.Type`. Therefore my question is what do you expect the `ListView` to display?

Comment: Just the name of the Type.

Comment: I just tried this and it actually works for me in an Android emulator.

Comment: Yes... I tried in Android emulator and the code works just fine (with or without DataTemplate). But on Windows machine, it does not work. I think this is a MAUI bug, I'll report it on Github Issues

Comment: Indeed, I can reproduce the issue on Windows as well. Seems like a bug.

Comment: First - use CollectionView. Second - always specify DataType. It is not recommended. It is required.

Comment: @H.A.H. I tried CollectionView, not working. I already specified DataType in the MainPage, so I guess it's okay?

Comment: @Nowayout it is not ok. As you can see from the answer of Alexander, he is converting Types to Strings. And again, make CollectionView, define your ItemTemplate, and set your DataType for it. This is the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue on Windows. And it turns out that the generic type parameter:  [T](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0#type-parameters) in [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0) can't be defined as [System.Type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=net-7.0).

And I notice that you open a new issue: [[Windows] ListView cannot bind to ObservableCollection<System.Type> #16911](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16911), you can follow up there.

As an alternative workaround, if you just want to display the name of the `Type` in ListView, you can convert it to `String` like below:

```
public ObservableCollection<string> _types = new ObservableCollection<string>() 
{
      typeof(int).ToString(), typeof(string).ToString(), typeof(double).ToString()
};
```

Comment: Can you provide more detail about why T in ObservableCollection cannot be System.Type? And why it works on Android but not on Windows?